The term 'search-Mailbox' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet
I am a total newbie on powershell with no guidance from someone more senior. I want to delete all meetings from a list of e-mail addresses. We are an educational organisation and want to remove all old cancelled meetings before scheduling the meetings in Teams for the new semester.
I've been able to connect powershell to our Microsoft tenant using the Connect-MsolService command and I can get a list of users using Get-MsolUser.
I've googled and found that I can delete all meetings from a calendar using this command
search-Mailbox -Identity xxxxxx@domain.com -SearchQuery "kind:meetings" -DeleteContent -confirm:$false -Force
But when I run it, I get
search-Mailbox : The term 'search-Mailbox' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
I am a Global Administrator on the tenant.
Any suggestions?

Usually there's some connect- command first, but you need the module and the rights.  It might be this:  Connect to Exchange Online PowerShell https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/connect-to-exchange-online-powershell?view=exchange-ps

I just want to add, please run these commands without -Delete-Content and -Force until you're satisfied with the results.  Also, you may be able to filter the returned results for only 'canceled' meetings.  Also, this works better if you target the account that set the meeting, because it will remove it from all the recipients calendars, or at least send an update email, and the recipient need only click 'remove from calendar'.

Like js2010 mentioned, you need to connect to Exchange:
Connect-ExchangeOnline -UserPrincipalName <UPN> [-ExchangeEnvironmentName <Value>] [-ShowBanner:$false] [-DelegatedOrganization <String>] [-SkipLoadingFormatData]

But you also need to have the correct permissions since only cmdlets you are allowed to run will be loaded.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/search-mailbox?view=exchange-ps

By default, Search-Mailbox is available only in the Mailbox Search or
Mailbox Import Export roles, and these roles aren't assigned to any
role groups. To use this cmdlet, you need to add one or both of the
roles to a role group (for example, the Organization Management role
group). Only the Mailbox Import Export role gives you access to the
DeleteContent parameter.

Your query, once you get the access to the cmdlet, will delete ALL meetings for the specified mailbox, you might want to consider adding some kind of timespan to the query as well.

And have the ExchangeOnlineManagement module.

Search-Mailbox is only available to onprem system for cloud based system Microsoft want you to use
New-ComplianceSearch -Name "Remove older than 30 days messages" -ExchangeLocation email -ContentMatchQuery "(Received >= 05/20/2024)"


Do we have any restrictions on making a compliance search and deleting content using MS365? The users are using the business standard license.
